# Include pure javascript cesium overlay with angular cesium

Tags: javascript, angular, cesiumjs

I'm using angular 4+ and trying to integrate cesium. I have the globe working, and I'm trying to add overlays that have been built by another dev in pure js. I installed npm angular-cesium to get the map running, and i'm trying to include the js file to manipulate it (the angular-cesium devs said this was possible, but did not explain how)

I put the file globe.js in my component folder, and included it in the component like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
require('./globe.js')
declare var Cesium: any;

@Component({
    selector: 'app-globe',
    templateUrl: './globe.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./globe.component.css'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class GlobeComponent implements OnInit {
    startup: any;

    constructor() {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        startup()
    }

}
```

it is clear that the globe.js file and function are imported and accessable in my component,
but i'm getting the error

```
globe.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'Cesium' in 'globe'
```

Somehow Cesium is not getting imported to globe. How do I fix this? is this the wrong way to integrate js with cesium angular?

Comment: `import * as Cesium from './globe'`?

Comment: i tried. it says this is not a module. but as stated in the question, this is getting my javascript i think, but the cesium object is not being imported. trying to figure where to get that...

Comment: Can you try installing from npm and import/require from there?

Comment: i installed cesium with npm, got the globe running with angular-cesium, required the js file in my component

Comment: After looking in the docs it sounds like it would be easiest to set it up as you would outside of Angular and do what is necessary to get TypeScript to not complain (e.g. `declare`).

Comment: yeah. tried that, don't know if i'm not following the steps right, or what.